Install a TypeScript package from GitHub repository subfolder
I'm using react-select on my ReactJS module, and I needed to make some changes to fit my needs.
But now, I'm trying to install my own fork using NPM, and it doesn't work.
Error message:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-select'

Tried using gitpkg with the following commands, and it did not work.
npm install 'willnaoosmith/react-select'
npm install 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/willnaoosmith/react-select/packages/react-select?master'
npm install -B 'willnaoosmith/react-select'

The module uses TypeScript, and my changes are on the packages/react-select.
When I try to install it using npm install 'willnaoosmith/react-select' it creates a @react-select/monorepo entry on my package.json
When I try to install using npm install 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/willnaoosmith/react-select/packages/react-select?master' it doesn't create the dist folders on the directories inside node_modules/react-select/packages/react-select/
What am I missing?

If you only want to test your changes locally before publishing to ensure they work you can follow the steps below:
Say, you're developing an app called A and B is the react-select package you made changes to locally, then:

Go to the project folder for B and enter npm link - this will
create a local package called B.
Now go to your project (A) folder
and enter npm link B - this will link your project to the local
package (B).

Any changes you make to B should reflect in A without having to publish it.
Another option is to use your repository directory with the following steps:

Push your code changes from your updated package to GitHub
Tag the just pushed commit
In your project, run npm install github_username/repository#tag

You can see the following link for details

npm install github_username/repository#tag didn't work. I tried using the directory inside my fork, and it doesn't build the dist files like npm install react-select does.

Did you open the link I posted for more details? It might be more thorough than my answer.

Solution: Had to publish my own package version.
Bye
